# How to make vanilla emacs properly indent C/C++ code using the '\t' character instead of 2 (or 1) spaces

Tags: emacs, indentation

My emacs always indents my C/C++ code using 2 (or 1) spaces instead of the '\t' character like I would want it to. I have tried `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)`, but that does nothing. Doing `M-i` does insert an actual tab character, but as soon as I enter either "()" or ";", it removes the '\t' character and inserts 2 spaces.

Yes, I have tried using c++-mode-hook, but it uses 4 spaces instead of a '\t' character.

Also, If that is not possible, I would rather have the auto-indentation disabled.

Here's my init.el file:

```
;;Start package.el with emacs:
(require 'package)
;;Add Melpa to repository list:
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;;Initialize package.el:
(package-initialize)

;;Install auto-complete:
(package-install 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete)
;;Use default config for every startup:
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)

;;Install yasnippet:
(package-install 'yasnippet)
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

;;Install auto-complete-c-headers mode:
(package-install 'auto-complete-c-headers)

;;Inhibits startup message: 
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)

;;Make emacs use tabs instead of spaces for indenting:
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)

;;Turn on electric pair mode (ie. auto-close brackets):
(electric-pair-mode 1)

;;Turn on gdb-many-windows mode:
(setq gdb-many-windows t)
```

PS. I find the emacs config file format to be such a mess and I don't know elisp like at all.

PS. If there is a flavour of emacs that already does this and is good for using as a C/C++ IDE, then please tell me.

Comment: Don’t you need to set `tab-width` if you want a tab that’s only two spaces wide (visually)?

Answer (score 2):

The `indent-tabs-mode` variable is [buffer-local](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer_002dLocal-Variables.html), this means that if you use `setq`, then the change is applicable only to the local buffer - the `init.el` in your case.

Instead, you can customize it in the [hook for C++ mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/CC-Hooks.html), something like this:

```
(defun my/c++-hook ()
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
  (setq tab-width 4)
  )
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'alexott/c-c++-hook)
```

P.S. You can look into [my config for CCMode](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-ccmode.el)

Comment: Alternatively use `(setq-default intent-tabs-mode t tab-width 4)`